# Image upload in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying to add o image widget in odoo screeen,

I have used the field as below ,

```py
  image = fields.Binary("Image", attachment=True,
                          help="This field holds the image used as avatar for \
        this contact, limited to 1024x1024px",)
```

XML :

```xml
<field name="image" widget='image' class="oe_avatar"/>
```

The uploaded image has white space around image, how to upload image as it is , without adding white space around image ?

Comment: Are you inheriting a model from an odoo module like `res.partner` from base? Or is it fully new model with this `Binary` field above?

Comment: inheriting event.event module

Comment: How big (length, width) are the tested images?

Comment: it will vary for all image

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thinned down snippet of my code where I stored an image to be used in a QWeb report.

```py
from openerp import api, fields, models, tools
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"  

    partner_report_image = fields.Binary(string='Report image', compute='_get_image')

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('image')
    def _get_image(self):
        for rec in self:
            rec.partner_report_image = tools.image_resize_image_medium(
                rec.image, size=(500, 500))
```

You should check out **openerp/tools/image.py** it has some pretty neat image processing functions. Hope this helps!